# Best way to pass arguments to a lambda in a hashmap in Java

Tags: java, lambda

I have a CLI which accepts different commands. In order to avoid an extensibly long switch statement, I decided to put my commands in a hashmap and have a single function that checks if the command exists and then calls it if it does.

```java
public class Commands {
  private LinkedHashMap<String, Runnable> commands = new LinkedHashMap<String, Runnable>();

  public Commands(Scanner userInput) {
    commands.put("foo", () -> this.foo());
    commands.put("bar", () -> this.bar());
    commands.put("foobar", () -> this.foobar());
    ... and so on 
  }

  private void handleCommand(String command) {
    if (!commands.containsKey(command)) {
      System.out.printf("'%s' is an invalid command%n", command);
      return;
    }

    commands.get(command).run();
  }

  public void foo() { ... }
  public void bar() { ... }
  public void foobar() { ... }
}
```

This has worked wonders and I've been able to quickly add lots of commands.

I now have an issue where some of my commands require arguments. eg `$ foo arg1 arg2` and I want to keep the structure I have as I originally wrote it this way because I thought it would be easy to extend.

I have changed up my handleCommand() method like so:

```java
  private void handleCommand(String command) {
    // Split the command to get possible args
    String[] args = command.split(" ");

    if (!commands.containsKey(args[0])) { // the first string is the command we want
      System.out.printf("'%s' is an invalid command%n", args[0]);
      return;
    }

    commands.get(args[0]).run(Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 1, args.length));
  }
```

and modifying the appropriate methods like so

```java
    ...
    commands.put("foo", (args) -> this.foo(args));
    ...

    public void foo(String[] args) { ... };
```

I have also tried using an Interface where I override `run`, I've tried using Callable instead of Runnable. I am just at a loss what to try now. A lot of the examples I've found are much much more complex than what I need and I struggle to follow them.

I am coming from a javascript background where it's perfectly fine to do:

```js
obj = { foo: (args) => { ...do something with args } }

obj.foo(args)
```

So this is my thinking behind why I want to do it this way.

TIA

Comment: There's not even a question mark included in your text, so what's the question?

Comment: How do I pass arguments to a lambda stored in a hashmap?

Comment: Since Java 8 you could replace the `Runnable` with a `Consumer` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Consumer` instead of `Runnable`. `Consumer` accept a parameter and returns nothing. If you want also to return a param you need to use `Function`.
So your code will look like this:

```
private LinkedHashMap<String, Consumer<String[]>> commands = new LinkedHashMap<>();

public Commands(Scanner userInput) {
    commands.put("foo", this::foo); // with method reference. Its the same as next line
    commands.put("bar", input -> this.bar(input));
    commands.put("foobar", input -> this.foobar(input));
}

....
commands.get(command).accept(args); // Consumer's methods is accept
```

You can check predefined functional interfaces [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using `Consumer<String[]>`, you can also define a custom interface for your commands to implement:

```
public static interface Command {
    public void run(String ... args);
}
```

To use exactly as you would expect:

```
private LinkedHashMap<String, Command> commands = new LinkedHashMap<>();

commands.put("foo", (input) -> foo(input));
```

Don't be afraid of declaring your own specific interfaces.

Comment: Ahhh! Thanks!I actually tried that following something else I found but couldn’t work out how to declare the lambda itself as a kind of that interface! 

Of course it makes sense to declare that in the hashmap silly me!